# How to fetch only 1 row from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I want to fetch the id of only 1 row from my database for my change password. So that it will only change the password of that specific id selected. This code says an error, $id is undefined.

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ofad");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) == 0 ){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    ?>

    <input type="text" class="input-field" name="id" value="<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>" required>

    <div class="input-field">
        <label>Current Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input" name="oldPass" placeholder="Current Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input"  name="newPass" placeholder="New Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
        <label>Confirm New Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input" name="confirmPass" placeholder="Confirm New Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" id="click" name="save_btn">
        <label for="click" class="save-me">Save</label>
        <!--MODAL POPUP-->
    </div>
<?php
        }
    }      
?>
```

Comment: So, you say `So that it will only change the password of that specific id selected.` and you say `I want to fetch the id..`, if the user has the id, why do you want to fetch it?

Comment: I made the id hidden. I want to fetch the id from the database because it is my primary key. So that it will only get the data of that ID selected.

Comment: The error is telling you that `id` is not defined, and I can see where you are defining the variable called `id`? Because you are using that variable in your query.

Comment: Yes because I am trying to fetch only 1 row from the database. If I remove the WHERE in the query, it prints all data in the database. How can I fetch only 1 row from the database? Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting it to get only the ID of the current, logged in user? If so, you should be able to get the ID from the Session

Comment: Yes I would like to do that

Comment: OK. So what is preventing you from taking the value from the Session then?

Comment: How can I get the value from the session?

Comment: `$id = $_SESSION["userID"];` - same as how you access any other variable. Obviously that's just an example, i don't know exactly what the name of the correct field in your session is - consult your login code to see what it sets when the user is successfully logged in. Make sure to run `session_start();` before trying to access session variables though. If you're not familiar with PHP sessions there are plenty of free tutorials online you can follow, just search for it

Answer (score 1):

all the problem is in $id, it has not variable to defined it, so add line before the SQL query defined the $id.

as example: $id = 5; (5 is your ID number in database)

another problem may appear to you
in 'if' statement your condition is: if there is no rows run the while function

to resolve this, change the statement with
(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) != 0)

or (mysqli_num_rows($query_run) == 1) -- as you sure there is single row

Comment: Can I put $id = $_POST['id']; instead? How can I define the array if I put it? Because I want to get the ID of the user who is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If a user is logged in you start a session and use his credentials like e.g. the username here:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$username = $_POST["username"];
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
?>
```

Now you can query the ID belonging to the username on the following pages.
Use prepared statements to prevent sql injections.
Here is an example with mysqli.
You have to adjust the column names to those of your admin table:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$valueSearch = "";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ofad");
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT `ID` FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($valueSearch);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($connection);
print $valueSearch;
}
?>
```